# Probability of a binary outcome

Tags: logistic, binary-data

I am a little confused with a simple problem.  Say I have an event that can either occur or not occur everyday.  The underlying distribution of occurrence or non-occurrence is unknown, there is no additional variable to use for prediction.  I just want to describe what happened in the last 7 days.  The event occurred in 2 of the last 7 days. My colleague wants to say either:

- The probability of the event occurring is 2/7 or 29%
- The probability of the event occurring is p=2/(7+1) or 25% (Weibull formula)

I think that neither of the above is a true "probability", and that a description should just say "the event occurred on 29% of the days".

If we did want to describe the probability of the event happening over the long term, we would have to assume a distribution and fit the distribution to our data.  How would we do that?

Comment: Saying "the event occurred in 2 of the last 7 days" is clear and accurate.  Saying "the event occurred on $\frac27$ of the days in the last week" is slightly less clear.

Comment: Can you clarify (reference, link or explain what is your "Weibull formula"?